# Error al consumir servicio

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

Tengo un problema al consumir un servicio Rest con Jquery, no tengo problema con herramientas como Insomnia o el navegador.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://sanguchi.esy.es/peoples",
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) { 
       alert("success");
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, status) { 
         alert("error"); //Siempre ejecuta esto
       }
});
```

Lo que debería retornar es lo siguiente:

```
[{ "id": "1","nombre": "aaaa" }, {"id": "2",  "nombre": "bbb"}   ]
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Ejecuta el metodo de "error"

Comment: Agrega para mostrar el posible problema =>   alert("error: " + jqXHR + " , status:" + status); //Siempre ejecuta esto

Comment: "error: [object Object] , status:error"

Comment: jqXHR->  readyState = 0,
responseJSON = undefined,
status = 0,
statusText = "error"

Comment: Te presento tu error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://sanguchi.esy.es/peoples. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: por cierto, peoples no existe, es people, es como decir gentes -> usas el plural para referir a otro plural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conociendo que utilizas hostinger, andas `PHP` en el backend entonces agrega el header:

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

y/o en tu archivo `.htaccess`:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, tu solución me funciono bien con IE, pero sigue dando error de CORS en Firefox.  `Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://sanguchi.esy.es/peoples (razón: la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no coincide con '*, *').`

Comment: No entiendo como supiste el url si nunca se especifico en la prengunta??? Es tu companero de trabajo o que sucedio =0

Comment: considero que soy un desarrollador web muy curioso :D @Elenasys utilizar las "Developer Tools" -> tecla F12 y ver la consola cuando ejecutaba el código mostrado.

Comment: @Chipilo acabo de probar el código con Internet Explorer y quiere descargar el json, acabo de revisar con Firefox (edición normal y edición developer) y me muestra el json, de la misma manera Google Chrome

Comment: Ok fredyfx ya veo la url ! =) Saludos!

Comment: Para que me funcione en Firefox y Chrome, tuve que agregar la siguiente línea al servicio:   `<?php    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");`

Comment: una vez mas, muchas gracias @fredyfx

Comment: De nada mi estimado, dale con todo el power 2.0! Éxitos y bendiciones con el desarrollo :D